# How to write unit testcase to check if input file is a csv file (with assert statement) using python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, testcase

I have already witten a python code to convert json file to csv file in **pycharm IDE** like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.read_json(r"json file path")
df.to_csv(r"csv file path")


def read_data(data):
    with open(data, "r") as f:
        data = [row for row in csv.reader(f.read().splitlines())]
        return data
data = "generatedcsvfilename.csv"
read_data(data)
```

Now I have to read the generated csv file to write **unit testcases** in python.

**POSSIBLE TESTCASES**:

1. To check if CSV file has been generated from json file in the specified folder.
2. To check if the file extension is .csv
3. To check if the CSV file is not empty.

Please help me to write unit testcases for the above listed testcases in python

*Suggest me some more possible testcases if any.*

Comment: I think most indentations are wrong in the code snippet. Can you fix them?

Comment: I think that checking for a .csv file extension is better handled in the program logic rather than in a test - the purpose of `read_data()` is to accept a filepath, so the first operation in that function should be to validate the filepath before even trying to open it.

Comment: @jidicula Okay then I think I should call this function read_data() in my testcase program. Will that be fine?.. If so help me in doing that.

Comment: Take a look at pytest's landing page: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/  for a good example.